# Add or remove input controls on the fly using jQuery,Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I was going through the code  given in [this](https://bootstrapfriendly.com/blog/dynamically-add-or-remove-form-input-fields-using-jquery/#google_vignette) link, for adding  input controls like textboxes, dropdown lists etc in my form.

but when i tried to modify, the code, with addition of new dropdownlists, am not getting the results properly. Alignment was wrong and label is not coming as expected.
here is my updated code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <label> entity name </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label> Operator </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12 p-0">
      <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer p-0">
        <div class="row form_field_outer_row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control w_90" name="mobileb_no[]" id="mobileb_no_1" 
          placeholder="Enter entity name." />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <select name="no_type[]" id="no_type_1" class="form-control" >
              <option>--Select Field Name--</option>
              <option>--state1--</option>
              <option>--state2--</option>
              <option>--state3--</option>
            </select>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <select name="no_type[]" id="no_type_1" class="form-control" >
              <option>--Select attribute --</option>
              <option>--attributes1--</option>
              <option>--attributes2--</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <select name="no_type[]" id="no_type_1" class="form-control" >
              <option> --Select entity -- </option>
              <option> entity1 </option>
              <option> entity2 </option>
              
            </select>
          </div>
```

my requirement is to add 3 more dropdown lists and 2 checkboxes.
but when I tried to add the dropdown lists/ label titles , am getting those in a unexpected results.

[form-with-dynamic-controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8jYq.png)

in order to get the correctly aligned form controls - with proper titles, etc
where n which  tags i need to modify?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't add cdn's in your code. You can also take the code from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sumit_sharmaXD/t2prjy41/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click",".add_new_frm_field_btn", function (){ 
      console.log("clicked");
      var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;
      $(".form_field_outer").append(`
          <div class="row form_field_outer_row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control w_90" name="mobileb_no[]" id="mobileb_no_${index}" placeholder="Enter mobiel no." />
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control w_90" name="mobileb_no[]" id="mobileb_no_${index}" placeholder="Enter mobiel no." />
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select name="no_type[]" id="no_type_${index}" class="form-control" >
                  <option>--Select type--</option>
                  <option>Personal No.</option>
                  <option>Company No.</option>
                  <option>Parents No.</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select name="no_type[]" id="no_type_${index}" class="form-control" >
                  <option>--Select type--</option>
                  <option>Personal No.</option>
                  <option>Company No.</option>
                  <option>Parents No.</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer">
                <button class="btn_round add_node_btn_frm_field" title="Copy or clone this row">
                  <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
                </button>

                <button class="btn_round remove_node_btn_frm_field" disabled>
                  <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </button>
                <input style="margin-left:10px;" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"  value="Checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1"> Checkbox1</label>
              </div>
            </div>
        `);

      $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);
      $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field").first().prop("disabled", true);
    });
 });


    ///======Clone method
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click", ".add_node_btn_frm_field", function (e) {
      var index = $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;
      var cloned_el = $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_row").clone(true);

      $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer").last().append(cloned_el).find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);

      $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field").first().prop("disabled", true);

    
      //change id
      $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").last().find("input[type='text']").attr("id", "mobileb_no_"+index);

      $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").last().find("select").attr("id", "no_type_"+index);

      console.log(cloned_el);
      //count++;
    });
 });


$(document).ready(function(){
    //===== delete the form fieed row
    $("body").on("click", ".remove_node_btn_frm_field", function () {
      $(this).closest(".form_field_outer_row").remove();
      console.log("success");
    });
  });
```

```css
.btn_round {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn_round:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6b4acc;
  border: 1px solid #6b4acc;
}
.btn_content_outer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85%;
}
.close_c_btn {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ededed;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #ff5c5c;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.add_icon {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.add_group_btn {
  display: flex;
}
.add_group_btn i {
  font-size: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.add_group_btn span {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
.add_group_btn,
.clone_sub_task {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sub_task_append_area .custom_square {
  cursor: move;
}
.del_btn_d {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/AdminLTE.min.css" />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <title>
      Dynamically add or remove form input fields using jQuery -
      bootstrapfriendly
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container py-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 form_sec_outer_task border">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 bg-light p-2 mb-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <h4 class="frm_section_n">Form Title</h4>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label>Mobile No.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <label> Type </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 p-0">
            <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer p-0">
              <div class="row form_field_outer_row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control w_90"
                    name="mobileb_no[]"
                    id="mobileb_no_1"
                    placeholder="Enter mobiel no."
                  />
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control w_90"
                    name="mobileb_no[]"
                    id="mobileb_no_1"
                    placeholder="Enter mobiel no."
                  />
                </div>
                
                
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <select name="no_type[]" id="no_type_1" class="form-control">
                    <option>--Select type--</option>
                    <option>Personal No.</option>
                    <option>Company No.</option>
                    <option>Parents No.</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <select name="no_type[]" id="no_type_1" class="form-control">
                    <option>--Select type--</option>
                    <option>Personal No.</option>
                    <option>Company No.</option>
                    <option>Parents No.</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer">
                  <button
                    class="btn_round add_node_btn_frm_field"
                    title="Copy or clone this row"
                  >
                    <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn_round remove_node_btn_frm_field" disabled>
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                  </button>
                  <input style="margin-left:10px;" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"  value="Checkbox1">
  <label for="checkbox1"> Checkbox1</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ml-0 bg-light mt-3 border py-3">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-lite py-0 add_new_frm_field_btn">
              <i class="fas fa-plus add_icon"></i> Add New field row
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 pt-4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have already taken that code and my requirement is to add few more input fields, 2 dropdown lists, 1 checkbox and 1 textbox, in the initial row. and when i click on + button/add button, the same row -<div> has to be repeated , immediately below,. when i added more input controls based on reqmnt, am not getting the correct alignemnt, dislocated manner,. am looking for, how to add few more controls in the existing form.

Comment: I have updated the code you can check

Comment: @DasAD Please tick if you got the answer.